# How do I read multiple files after click opened in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c++-cli

I have set a multiselect function in my code to allow me to open multiple files which is in ".txt" forms. And here is the problem, how am I going to read all these selected files after it opened through OpenFileDialog? The following codes and at the "for each" line, when I use System::Diagnostics::Debug, it shows only the data from a file, while data of other files were missing. How should I modify the code after the "for each"? Can anyone provide some suggestions or advice? The files selected are as 1_1.txt, 2_1.txt, 3_1.txt. Appreciate your reply and Thanks in advance.

Here is my written code,

```
Stream^ myStream;  
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;  
openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";  
openFileDialog1->Title = "open captured file";  
openFileDialog1->Filter = "CP files (*.cp)|*.cp|All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";  
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;  
openFileDialog1->Multiselect = true;  

if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )  
{  
  array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1->FileName);  
  for each (String^ line in lines) {  
    //?????  
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("",line);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: @user931794 It's C++/CLI

Comment: Ken you have it's `Tag C#`

Comment: @DJKRAZE Another user had edited it - I fixed it.

Comment: @ReedCopsey sorry about that. I saw the ^s and panicked.

Comment: Reed looks to have the correct answer now that the code has been properly depicted in `C++`

Comment: Thanks for the amendments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [`OpenFileDialog.FileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx) property if you allow multiple files to be selected:

```
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )  
{  
  for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->FileNames) 
  {  
    array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(file);  
    for each (String^ line in lines) 
    {  
      System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("",line);  
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: There's no c++ example provided over there cause I'm still quite new to this and not familiar to the conversion of c# to c++. It is ok if I request an example or guidance?

Comment: @Ken The above should work - what don't you understand from my code sample?

Comment: Sorry, I don't realize the code was actually different from mine. It works after I tried, thank you very much for your help and your time. Sorry for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) property.

C# version (should be easy to adapt for C++):

```
foreach (var file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me c++ version? Cause I'm still new to it and not familiar with the conversion from c# to c++. And inside the bracket that you shown, is it to include whatever process that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use `openFileDialog1->FileNames`. It returns the multiple filenames that you selected

Read here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx
its in C# but, it will be easy to extrapolate to C++.